# create custom page, after the install is complete

Tags: nsis, electron-builder

I am working on a script that is installing my application made in electron and so far all seems to be working fine. There is one problem however, i was able to add new custom page, but it is added before the install is taking place. It is a problem because this page contains two input fields which user must fill and then the provided data is stored in directory where app is installed. But because app is installed after this step, directory gets overwritten and file is gone. This is the code:

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

XPStyle on

Var Dialog
Var UserLabel
Var UserText
Var UserState
Var PassLabel
Var PassText
Var PassState

Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave

Function nsDialogsPage

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Username:"
    Pop $UserLabel

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% 12u $UserState
    Pop $UserText

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 39u 100% 12u "Password:"
    Pop $PassLabel

    ${NSD_CreatePassword} 0 52u 100% 12u $PassState
    Pop $PassText

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function nsDialogsPageLeave

    ${NSD_GetText} $UserText $UserState
    ${NSD_GetText} $PassText $PassState

    ${If} $UserState == ""
        MessageBox MB_OK "Username is missing."
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${If} $PassState == ""
        MessageBox MB_OK "Password is missing."
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    StrCpy $1 $UserState
    StrCpy $2 $PassState

    FileOpen $9 $INSTDIR\credentials.txt w
    FileWrite $9 "$1:$2"
    FileClose $9
    SetFileAttributes $INSTDIR\credentials.txt HIDDEN|READONLY

FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

So yes the best would be to have this page after the installation, not before. Thank you for all the directions, i am totally new to NSIS so i have no clue how to accomplish this.

Comment: Your example code is missing all the other page lines and your question is about page order!

Comment: i tried to put other pages, but then they are executed twice, for example if you put `Page InstFiles` it will install app and then again fire default installer and install again, probably something is configured that way in electron-builder, i dont know why its happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages are displayed in the same order as they appear in your source file so you can just do:

```
Page Directory
Page InstFiles
Page Custom MyPage
```

Ideally you should collect the required information before the installation step (`InstFiles`) and you are almost there already. Your custom page is storing the information in global variables, all you have to do is to move the `File*` operations to a `Section`. If you do it this way then your custom page can appear any time before the `InstFiles` page.

Comment: ah i tried that but if i do this installer is executing installation twice, for some reason after custom MyPage it again runs default installer, i suppose it has something to do with electron-builder compiling it.

Comment: That is possible, I don't know how electron-builder works. Then you have to settle for my other suggestion and just split collecting and writing into two different steps at different times.

Answer (score 0):

There are [customPageAfterChangeDir macros](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib/templates/nsis/assistedInstaller.nsh#L45) you can change to insert page before install and [customFinishPage macros](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/b9c1e52920c0613bf7d0ebebcce4144bafc49a1d/packages/app-builder-lib/templates/nsis/assistedInstaller.nsh#L50) after install.
Example if installer.nsh

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

!macro customPageAfterChangeDir
Page custom customPageCreator customPageLeave "Custom page caption"

Var Dialog

Function customPageCreator
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog
    
    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf} 
    
    MessageBox MB_OK "customPageCreator"

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function customPageLeave
    MessageBox MB_OK "customPageLeave"
FunctionEnd
!macroend
```