# Electron Installer Ask Product Key - Electron builder

Tags: windows, macos, electron, electron-builder

I am using electron builder v22.7.0 for building distributable Binary for Win and OSX. I want to add one more step in installer where I will ask user to paste LICENSE key/file and i want to make call to server for validating it.

If License is valid i want to continue installation or else show error.

I am not sure on how to add extra installation step using electron builder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185663/add-custom-page-field-to-nsis-setup-created-with-electron-builder

Comment: @Tobias : Thanks for the answer, I think this works for Windows only, how can i achieve the same for MACOS ?

Comment: i think you must pack as pkg on mac and use scripts, but not shure about that